# Copy a row but with some modifications

Tags: r

I have a large data set like this:

```
SUB SMOKE AMT  MDV ADDL II  EVID
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 1    0    20   0   16   24   1
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    50   0   24   12   1
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
...
```

I want to copy the row where `EVID=1` and insert it below, but for the copied row, `AMT`,`ADDL`,`II` and `EVID` should all equal to `0`, `SMOKE` and `MDV` remain the same. The expected output should look like this:

```
SUB SMOKE AMT  MDV ADDL II  EVID
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 1    0    20   0   16   24   1
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 1    0    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    50   0   24   12   1
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
 2    1    0    0   0    0    0
...
```

Does anyone have idea about realizing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# repeat EVID=0 rows 1 time and EVID=1 rows 2 times
r <- rep(1:nrow(DF), DF$EVID + 1) 
DF2 <- DF[r, ]

# insert zeros
DF2[duplicated(r), c("AMT", "ADDL", "II", "EVID")] <- 0
```

giving:

```
> DF2
    SUB SMOKE AMT MDV ADDL II EVID
1     1     0   0   0    0  0    0
2     1     0  20   0   16 24    1
2.1   1     0   0   0    0  0    0
3     1     0   0   0    0  0    0
4     1     0   0   0    0  0    0
5     2     1   0   0    0  0    0
6     2     1  50   0   24 12    1
6.1   2     1   0   0    0  0    0
7     2     1   0   0    0  0    0
8     2     1   0   0    0  0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
> t2 <- t[t$EVID==1,] # t is your data.frame
> t2[c("AMT","ADDL","II","EVID")] <- 0
> t2
  SUB SMOKE AMT MDV ADDL II EVID
2   1     0   0   0    0  0    0
6   2     1   0   0    0  0    0
> rbind(t,t2)
   SUB SMOKE AMT MDV ADDL II EVID
1    1     0   0   0    0  0    0
2    1     0  20   0   16 24    1
3    1     0   0   0    0  0    0
4    1     0   0   0    0  0    0
5    2     1   0   0    0  0    0
6    2     1  50   0   24 12    1
7    2     1   0   0    0  0    0
8    2     1   0   0    0  0    0
21   1     0   0   0    0  0    0 # this row
61   2     1   0   0    0  0    0 # and this one are new
```